# How i Can Decrease the loading time of Crystal Report File

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

How i can Decrease the report file Loading Time?
I Use this Code to Load a Report File

```
reportDocumnet.Load(reortFilePath);
```

but the first time loading is very long.

just in first time running this code

i want use a way to run this line of my code speedly

Comment: As @dotjoe has said, the delay is on first time running of a crystal report so the slowness your are experiencing will be due to the loading of all the crystal components. Putting the crystal components into the GAC if possible might resolve this issue but would require some investigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some people load a report in background thread on program startup. Then the massive crystal libraries will be loaded when user runs the first report.

Answer (score 1):

To follow on with what has been said about preloading crystal libraries have a look at this article

http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.experts-exchange.com%2FDatabase%2FReporting_%2FCrystal_Reports%2FQ_24295843.html&btnG=Google+Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=

Comment: bold move linking to expert sexchange :) why can you only see the answers if linked from google search? http://www.google.com/search?q=Slow+opening+of+Crystal+Reports+in+.NET+Run+time&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: @dotjoe Bizarre! Changed link to ensure anyone using will reach answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How much time spent in the SQL/data plan generation? Can you create a view in your database to speed up the content resolution? Can you cache previously generated reports that have the same query parameters?

Comment: just this line of my code runing in long time(in first time) And this not realated to load data